# STM32F429ZI DISC1: Keil printf not working

Tags: stm32f4

I am learning to program STM32F4 based micro controller(using STM32F429ZI DISC1 board). I am trying to use printf function to print out debug message. I have used following sources as reference and nothing worked for me

1. [STM32F7: Debug(printf) Viwer y Logic Analyzer en Keil 5](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ji1MbxQJSc8)
2. [Keil printf](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jRBdTLwnP9M)
3. [How to display printf output over SWO in Keil µVision](https://www.silabs.com/community/mcu/32-bit/knowledge-base.entry.html/2014/05/20/how_to_display_print-Ly1m)

This is my code

```
#include "stm32f4xx.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int msTicks = 0;
void SysTickHandler()
{
    msTicks++;
}

int fputc(int ch, FILE *f)
{
  ITM_SendChar(ch);
  return(ch);
}

int main(void)
{
    // Get the core clock frequency
    SystemCoreClockUpdate();

    if(SysTick_Config(SystemCoreClock/1000))                    // SysTick 1 ms interrupts
    {
        while(1);                                                                               // Capture error
    }

    printf("LED ON\r\n");
    while(1)
    {

    }
    return 0;
}
```

I have checked my core clock frequency, it's 16 MHz[image]
Did as shown in this [thread](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/uv4/uv4_db_dbg_printf_viewer.htm)
[image]

[image] 
[image]

Here's the link to my [project](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1PBJnZsURd8DTVB7JvmnwV5uDqo2quCn_)

Am I missing something??

Also what is that Xtal clock frequency in **Options for Target >> Target >> Xtal** if I'm using internal RC oscillator.

Comment: I could imagine Keil uses the XTAL Value to calculate the clock settings.
Maybe you could activate the Clock Output and measure the "real" µC frequency.

Comment: One reason I figured out for it not working is Solder bridge for SWO is not connected in board. SO I have to connect. Is it okay if I solder it together directly or use some resistor in series

Answer (score 1):

The code works.
By default STM32F429ZI DISC1 board comes with ST-Link's SWO input is connected to SWD connector, but not to the MCU.

[image]

Solder the Bridge SB9 and it works.
The other STM32F4 Discovery board that shown in the video comes with the bridge soldered by default